# Expect / Bash: Running a bash if statement in expect

Tags: bash, scripting, tcl, expect

I am trying to ssh into a server, and check if id_rsa.pub exists. If it does not exist, I would like to run ssh-keygen, otherwise I don't want to do anything.

I can run simply commands like "cat" or "rm" using send in Tcl/Expect, but when I try to do something like this it does not work:

```
send "if [ ! -f $USER_SSH_PATH/id_rsa.pub ]; then CREATE_FILE=true; fi\r"
expect "# " { }

send "if $CREATE_FILE; then; ssh-keygen -t rsa -C $USER -f $USER_SSH_PATH/id_rsa\r"
...
```

I get the following error message:
    # invalid command name "!"
        while executing
    "! -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub "
        invoked from within

Is it possible to run such a command please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets because it's part of tcl syntax:

```
send "if \[ ! -f $USER_SSH_PATH/id_rsa.pub \]; then CREATE_FILE=true; fi\r"
```

In tcl, `[]` works the same way ``` `` ``` or `$()` works in bash. So what's happening is that before executing the `send` command the interpreter first does a substitution on the string and it sees two things it needs to substitute:

1. $USER_SSH_PATH gets substituted with the value contained in the variable USER_SSH_PATH
2. [! ....] gets substituted with the result of calling the `!` function/command. Which as you discovered doesn't exist.

Note that in tcl (and by extension expect) variable and function names aren't limited to alphanumeric. It's valid to have variable and function names like `$` or `!` or even the NUL character (a byte with the value of 0):

```
proc ! {} {puts "!"}
proc "$" {} {puts "\$"}
proc \0 {} {puts "NUL character"}

!   ;# this prints !
\$  ;# this prints $
\0  ;# this prints "NUL character"
```

See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm for more information on tcl syntax.

Comment: This is the only answer which actually deals with the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That is actually what I needed, you fixed my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As slebetman already pointed out, the characters `[`, `]`, `$` and `\` have a special meaning inside `"`.

- `[` and `]` are used for command subsitution, so `[expr {2+3}]` would be replaced by `5` (the result).
- `$` is used for variable substitution.
- `\` is used for special characters (like `\r` for the character with the code point 13)

You can either escape those characters inside `"` with `\`: <sub>I assume that `$USER_SSH_PATH` is a local (tcl) variable</sub>

```
send "if \[ ! -f $USER_SSH_PATH/id_rsa.pub \]; then CREATE_FILE=true; fi\r"
```

or use `{` and `}` to surround your string.
If you use `{` and `}` no substitution will be done. This also includes that `\r` will be send as `\r` to the server, and not as single character.

There are a few other options to create such things:

- [`subst`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm) can do the substitution on a string. It is also possible that only certain kinds of substitution take place (use the `-nocommands` switch to prevent `[]` substitution, `-novariables` for `$` substitution and `-nobackslashes` for `\`)
  Example:

  ```
  send [subst -nocommands \
      {if [ ! -f $USER_SSH_PATH/id_rsa.pub ]; then CREATE_FILE=true; fi\r}]
  ```
- [`string map`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) to replace certain sequences.
  Example

  ```
  send [string map [list {@@r@@} \r {@@USER_SSH_PATH@@} $USER_SSH_PATH] \
     {if [ ! -f @@USER_SSH_PATH@@/id_rsa.pub ]; then CREATE_FILE=true; fi@@r@@}]
  ```

There are many ways to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your `$USER_SSH_PATH` ? Is it the same in your local and remote machine, meaning you have the right permission... The following may help you debug.

```
echo ${USER_SSH_PATH}
ssh <hostname> "
if [ ! -f ${USER_SSH_PATH}/id_rsa.pub ]; then
   echo ${USER_SSH_PATH};
   echo \"File Not Found, Creating....\";
   ssh-key-gen -t rsa -C ${USER} -f ${USER_SSH_PATH}/id_rsa;
else
   echo \"File Found\";
   exit 1;
fi
"
```

Comment: $USER_SSH_PATH is actually just /root/.ssh, thanks! I login as root on the server in the first place. I have to login using expect though, ssh-keygen is not set the first time.

Comment: I am not sure how your comment is helping, I am just trying to get an if statement be sent with expect.

Comment: The lines I wrote here will execute the `if statements` over the `ssh`  on the remote server, check for the `id_rsa.pub`. If the file doesn't exist, it will execute your `ssh-keygen` command. What I don't understand what extra do you want to achieve with `send` ?

Comment: I use expect to send the password if it is required. There is a bunch of "expect" and "send" that execute before, to see if the password is required. Your solution will not work because of that.

Comment: That's very unlikely to do the right thing. If done in bash, it's not addressing the question. If done in expect, it suffers from the same problem as the original question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I just thought about is to run "ls /root/.ssh/ | grep id_rsa.pub" in the send and look at the output with expect. I am curious how I could have run bash if commands though.

Either I'll get "id_rsa.pub" in return, or empty line. But if I have "id_rsa.pub*" it will break.

Anyone has an idea to improve this please? Thanks!